# Why is this unused string not garbage collected?

Tags: ruby, string, garbage-collection

Why does unused_variable_2 and unused_variable_3 get garbage collected, but not unused_variable_1?

```
# leaky_boat.rb
require "memprof"

class Boat
  def initialize(string)
    unused_variable1 = string[0...100]
    puts unused_variable1.object_id
    @string = string
    puts @string.object_id
  end
end

class Rocket
  def initialize(string)
    unused_variable_2 = string.dup
    puts unused_variable_2.object_id
    unused_variable_3 = String.new(string)
    puts unused_variable_3.object_id
    @string = string
    puts @string.object_id
  end
end

Memprof.start

text = "a" * 100
object_id_message = "Object ids of unused_variable_1, @string, unused_variable_2, unused_variable_3, and another @string"
before_gc_message = "Before GC"
after_gc_message = "After GC"
puts object_id_message
boat = Boat.new(text)
rocket = Rocket.new(text)
puts before_gc_message
Memprof.stats
ObjectSpace.garbage_collect
puts after_gc_message
Memprof.stats
Memprof.stop
```

Running the program:

```
$ uname -a
Linux [redacted] 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:30:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ruby --version # Have to use Ruby 1.8 - memprof doesn't work on 1.9
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby -rubygems leaky_boat.rb 
Object ids of unused_variable_1, @string, unused_variable_2, unused_variable_3, and another @string
70178323299180
70178323299320
70178323299100
70178323299060
70178323299320
Before GC
      2 leaky_boat.rb:6:String
      2 leaky_boat.rb:26:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:9:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:7:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:32:Rocket
      1 leaky_boat.rb:31:Boat
      1 leaky_boat.rb:29:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:28:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:27:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:20:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:18:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:17:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:16:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:15:String
After GC
      1 leaky_boat.rb:6:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:32:Rocket
      1 leaky_boat.rb:31:Boat
      1 leaky_boat.rb:29:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:28:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:27:String
      1 leaky_boat.rb:26:String
```

Comment: Andrew: Did my answer from last week not satisfactorily address your question?

Comment: @dbenhur it doesn't explain why `unused_variable_2` and `unused_variable_3` *does* get garbage collected - don't they have special cases to save memory allocations as well?

Comment: They don't have special shared allocations.  String#dup and String.new both guarantee that you get a distinct new object.  I'll add refs to the code path in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is because the string implementation of your version of ruby for substr has a special case to save memory allocations when you take a substr that is the tail of the source string and the string length is large enough to not store the string value in the base object structure.

If you trace the code, you see the range subscript `string[0...100]` will go through [this clause in rb_str_substr](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/string.c#L628).  So the new string will be allocated via [str_new3](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/string.c#L139) which allocates a new object struct (hence the differing object_id), but sets the string value `ptr` field as a pointer into the source object's extended storage and sets the `ELTS_SHARED` flag to indicate that the new object shares storage with another object.

In your code you take this new substring object and assign it to instance var `@string` which is still a live reference when you run garbage collection.  Since there's a live reference to the allocated storage of the original string, it can't be collected.

In ruby trunk, this optimization to share storage on compatible tail substrings appears to still exist.

The two other vars `unused_variable_2` and `unused_variable_3` don't have this extended storage sharing issue because they're set via mechanisms that assure distinct storage, so they get garbage collected as expected when their references pass out of scope.

String#dup runs [rb_str_replace](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/string.c#L2308) (via [initialize_copy binding](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/string.c#L4936)) which replaces the contents of the source string with a copy of the contents of the source string and assures that the storage is not shared.

String#new(source_str) runs through [rb_str_init](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/string.c#L337) which similarly assures distinct storage with rb_str_replace on the supplied initial value.

Comment: @NiklasB. Not as I read it. `beg + len == RSTRING(str)->len` says the beg+len of the sub-string slice matches the len of the source string, that is, they align at the end of the string.  The reason this is the case is that the code must have a c-null char at the end of the string, so the only substring slices which can use this shared storage are ones that have the same end of string.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. I was misled by the `0` part of `string[0...100]`. In this case it's both a prefix *and* a suffix, but the sharing indeed works on a suffix basis.

Comment: "String#dup runs rb_str_replace (via initialize_copy binding) which replaces the contents of the source string with a copy of the contents of the source string and assures that the storage is not shared." - so in other words, it deliberately avoids the optimization used by the substring method?

Comment: Also, a blog post called [Seeing double](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/18/seeing-double-how-ruby-shares-string-values) claimed that String#dup and String.new(source_str) uses the optimization in question, though I'm not sure how reliable the author of that post is.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Well, I'm relying on reading the actual code, not the blog post.  rb_str_replace clearly makes independent strings unless the source string is shared. If the receiver string is shared, it calls str_make_independent to break the sharing, if it's already independent, it resizes and memcpys.